# how to upgrade libexttextcat-data

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

sudo apt-get upgrade 
Los siguientes paquetes se han retenido:
  libexttextcat-data
0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1 no actualizados.
 Cualquier ayuda . Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution [Dependency issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2036513.html) . It's this, purge ppa: `sudo ppa-purge ppa:libreoffice/ppa` . And install the Quantal package on the Precise. You can manually download the correct packages from here:[Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/libexttextcat/3.2.0-2ubuntu1)
Note, that the package libexttextcat-data is the section quantal i386.
Then choose the correct section (Quantal i386 or Quantal amd64) for the package libexttextcat0.
After downloading those two, open terminal and go to the directory where they are and run this command (be sure there are no other*.deb packages): And install: `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. Now reboot